# transformer.transform(.. is throwing an IO exception/File not found exception

Tags: java, ioexception

```
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
                ewFile = barcoUtil.getEwFile(Ew_Thread.ewLogger);
                StreamResult result = new StreamResult(ewFile);
                System.out.println("Ok I have came here--->"+ewFile.getAbsolutePath());
                transformer.transform(source, result);
```

it generates FileNotFoundException

```
Ok I have came here--->F:\Barco\employwise-barco files\EW_2015-05-05 14-35-55.txt
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: F:\Barco\employwise-barco%20files\EW_2015-05-05%2014-35-55.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.createResultContentHandler(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:297)
```

But the file Already Exists.

My only doubt it , as the url in exception throwed is containing %20 in stead of spaces, it might be windows is not able to recognize path.

What else could be the reasons?

Comment: How do you load your XML file into `document`? Do you use `DocumentBuilder.parse`?

Comment: actually resolved it yesterday. used .getPath() on ewFile. Windows was unable to load the path with %20.

Comment: Good. I suggest you answer your own question and mark it as answered.

Comment: @Stephan I cann't accpet my own answer

Comment: I think you can do this in 2 days time (you should see a message that indicates this)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

resolved the issue Yesterday, problem was with path containing %20 as spaces. I change

StreamResult result = new StreamResult(ewFile);
to      `StreamResult result = new StreamResult(ewFile.getPath());`

and it worked.